# How to save a list as numpy array in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Is possible to construct a NumPy array from a python list?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend you to go through NumPy's  [Quickstart tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html), which will probably help with these basic questions.

You can directly create an array from a list as:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( [2,3,4] )
```

Or from a from a nested list in the same way:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( [[2,3,4], [3,4,5]] )
```

Comment: import numpy as np; and add np. before array(np.array([]);  for someone who might be confused

Comment: I would have put that syntax a little differently.  How about `import numpy as np` then `a = np.array ( [[2,3,4],[3,4,5]] )`  ?

Answer (score 43):

you mean something like this ?

```
from numpy  import array
a = array( your_list )
```

Answer (score 19):

[Yes it is:](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d3f8e5fe9b903f3c3b2a5c0dfceb60d71602cf93)

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 16):

You want to save it as a file?

```
import numpy as np

myList = [1, 2, 3]

np.array(myList).dump(open('array.npy', 'wb'))
```

... and then read:

```
myArray = np.load(open('array.npy', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [numpy.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html), for example to convert a list into an array:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> np.asarray(a)
array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose, you mean converting a list into a numpy array?
Then,

```
import numpy as np

# b is some list, then ...    
a = np.array(b).reshape(lengthDim0, lengthDim1);
```

gives you a as an array of list b in the shape given in reshape.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete example:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('filename','rb') as csvfile:
     cdl = list( csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter='\t'))
     print "Number of records = " + str(len(cdl))

#then later

npcdl = np.array(cdl)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 

... ## other code
```

some list comprehension

```
t=[nodel[ nodenext[i][j] ] for j in idx]
            #for each link, find the node lables 
            #t is the list of node labels
```

Convert the list to a numpy array using the array method specified in the numpy library.

```
t=np.array(t)
```

This may be helpful: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.creation.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
import numpy as np
a=[[1,1],[2,2]]
b=np.asarray(a)
print(type(b))
```

output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```