# Numpy array using expression

Tags: python, numpy

how can I create an np array using expression y1 = x, when x array is already defined

`x = [1,2,5,7]`

from this array x , I would like to create another array y1 using the expression

```
y1 = x
```

using numpy

Comment: I believe what you suggest should work: x = numpy.array([1,2,3]) ; y1=x

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951135/how-to-save-a-list-as-numpy-array-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a copy of the array it would be

```
import numpy as np
y1 = np.array(x)
```

Currently you just assign the list from x to y1. With this you create a new numpy array with the values from x.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my intention is to use expression y=x or y = 2x like that

Comment: Then you need to set x = np.array([1,2,5,7]). Than you can just put y = x or y=2x or whatever you want. But in this case x has to be a numpy array