# How to remove 'b' character from ndarray that is added by np.genfromtxt

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a text file which contains rows of information in the form of both strings, integers and floats, separated by white space, e.g.

HIP893     23_10    7         0.028 
     4
HIP1074    43_20     20    0.0141     1
HIP1325    23_10      7      0.02388      5
...

I've imported this data using the following line:

```
data=np.genfromtxt('98_info.txt', dtype=(object, object, int,float,float))
```

However when I do this I get an output of

```
[(b'HIP893', b'23_10', 7, 0.028, 4) 
 (b'HIP1074', b'43_20', 20, 0.0141, 1)
 (b'HIP1325', b'23_10', 7, 0.02388, 5)
  ... ]
```

Whereas I would like there to be no 'b' and instead:

```
[('HIP893', '23_10', 7, 0.028, 4.0) 
 ('HIP1074', '43_20', 20, 0.0141, 1.0)
 ('HIP1325', '23_10', 7, 0.02388, 5.0)
  ... ]
```

I have tried NumPy's core.defchararray but that gave me the error 'string operation on non-string array', I guess because my data is a combination of both strings and numbers maybe?

Is there some way to either remove the character but keep the data in an array or perhaps another way to load in the information that will keep the strings in quotation marks and the numbers without them?

If there is a way to import it in that form as a 2d np array even better, but that is not an issue if not.

Thanks!

Comment: the "b" character denotes a bytes sequence:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: What do you get with `dtype=None`.

Comment: That's just the representation of the data, not part of the data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your sample and `dtype`:

```
In [1]: np.genfromtxt('stack55810419.txt', dtype=(object, object, int,float,floa
   ...: t))                                                                     
Out[1]: 
array([(b'HIP893', b'23_10',  7, 0.028  , 4.),
       (b'HIP1074', b'43_20', 20, 0.0141 , 1.),
       (b'HIP1325', b'23_10',  7, 0.02388, 5.)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

With `dtype=None` (and `encoding=None`):

```
In [5]: np.genfromtxt('stack55810419.txt', dtype=None, encoding=None)           
Out[5]: 
array([('HIP893', 2310,  7, 0.028  , 4),
       ('HIP1074', 4320, 20, 0.0141 , 1),
       ('HIP1325', 2310,  7, 0.02388, 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U7'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<i8')])
```

Specifying unicode dtypes (have to include a size):

```
In [6]: np.genfromtxt('stack55810419.txt', dtype=('U7', 'U7', int,float,float)) 
Out[6]: 
array([('HIP893', '23_10',  7, 0.028  , 4.),
       ('HIP1074', '43_20', 20, 0.0141 , 1.),
       ('HIP1325', '23_10',  7, 0.02388, 5.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U7'), ('f1', '<U7'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

I'm puzzled as to why the `None` case chooses a integer dtype for the 2nd column (the underscore should have prevented that).

`dtype=None` without the encoding parameter raises this warning:

> /usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.

In Py2 the default string type is bytestrings; in Py3 unicode. `genfromtxt` has used `bytestrings` in compatibility with py2.  But recent versions have added the `encoding` parameter.  But there still seems to be some rough edges to that conversion.

---

This may be why I got `i8`; Python's own `int` accepts the underscore.

```
In [20]: int('23_10')                                                           
Out[20]: 2310
```

Comment: What is the conclusion of these observations? Are you saying that using `dtype='U7'` is the preferred way?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `converters=` with a function that decodes your bytes strings, eg:

```
convs = dict.fromkeys([0, 1], bytes.decode)
data = np.genfromtxt('98_info.txt', dtype=(object, object, int, float, float), converters=convs)
```

Which gives you `data` of:

```
array([('HIP893', '23_10',  7, 0.028  , 4.),
       ('HIP1074', '43_20', 20, 0.0141 , 1.),
       ('HIP1325', '23_10',  7, 0.02388, 5.)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

the string followed by `b` are encoded string i.e., in `bytes`

You can decode them by applying `decode` function or just `str`

```
newData = [(str(x) if isinstance(x,bytes) else x for x in y) for y in data]
```

I think You can convert it in nparray via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951187/8071073) SO answer

> I really don't know about nparray

Comment: This will end up with a `list` though (not an `np.array`) containing tuples where *everything* has been converted to strings - even the items that are supposed to be `int` or `float`.